# Is it possible to draw a LineString across different features in Openlayers 7?

Tags: javascript, dictionary, openlayers, draw, layer

I've been working on an Openlayers map with draw support. The main purpose is to draw road connections across different roads, but these roads are all separate Features in OL. At this point, I can only draw a LineString across one Feature of the road network, always stopping when I arrive at a split. I want to continue drawing towards one of the other Features to make one long LineString, without having to click on the next Feature. Does anyone know if this is possible?

So in short, is it possible during drawing to connect a larger drawing Feature across these separate Features?

My code for the drawing of one feature:

```
    const roadLayer = useMemo(
    () =>
      new VectorLayer({
        background: 'transparent',
        source: new VectorSource({
          url: `****`,
          format: new GeoJSON(),
        }),
        style: new Style({
          stroke: new Stroke({
            width: 10,
            color: [77, 76, 254, 0],
          }),
        }),
      }),
    []
  );

  const drawVector = useMemo(
    () =>
      new VectorLayer({
        source: new VectorSource(),
        style: new Style({
          stroke: new Stroke({
            color: 'rgba(0, 205, 0, 1)', //finished line
            width: 4,
          }),
        }),
      }),
    []
  );

  const snapInteraction = new Snap({
    source: roadLayer?.getSource() as VectorSource<Geometry>,
  });

  const drawFeature = new Collection<Feature<LineString>>();

  const drawInteraction = new Draw({
    type: 'LineString',
    source: drawVector.getSource() as VectorSource<Geometry>,
    trace: true,
    features: drawFeature,
    traceSource: roadLayer.getSource() as VectorSource<Geometry>,
    style: new Style({
      stroke: new Stroke({
        color: 'rgba(255, 100, 100, 1)', //drawing line
        width: 4,
      }),
    }),
  });
```

Then a little lower I just add these on the mapObject:

```
let mapObject = new Map(options);
mapObject.addInteraction(drawInteraction);
mapObject.addInteraction(snapInteraction);
```

So far I've tried to do this but it's not working:

```
//found the segment on which user is hovering and is next segment:
    //trace this segment
    possibleSegments = possibleSegments.includes(hoveringFeature)
      ? possibleSegments
      : [...possibleSegments, hoveringFeature];
    setupSnapInteractions(possibleSegments);
    //start from this segment
    const allCoordinates = hoveringFeature.get('geometry').flatCoordinates;
    const coordinates = [allCoordinates[0], allCoordinates[1]];
    console.log(pixel);
    //drawInteraction.finishDrawing();
    drawInteraction.finishDrawing();
    const feature = new Feature(new LineString([coordinates]));
    drawInteraction.extend(feature);
    drawInteraction.setActive(true);
    snapInteraction.setActive(true);
```

Comment: Not sure what's the problem here. You can draw wherever you want, check the official examples: https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/draw-features.html